# VBA Excel: Paste large array to range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working in VBA for excel. I have an array called "aKey" (1 by 137,000 strings but exact size is subject to change so making code generic is a neccesity). I need to paste aKey to the first column of a a worksheet. So far i have tried 
     `Range(.Offset(1,0),.Offset(UBound(aKey)+1,0)).Value = aKey` 
but this seems to only paste 137,000 versions of the first entry of the array. 
I have also tried 
     `Range(.Offset(1,0),.Offset(UBound(aKey)+1,0)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aKey)`
 which also didn't work. Through a google search I did find that the Transpose function has a limited pasting size which may very well be the problem there. Does anybody know of a method to avhieve my goal? Thanks

Comment: Create a second array (137k x 1) and copy the contents from the first array (in a loop - will be fast), then drop that second array to the worksheet.

Comment: have also tried Range("A2").Resize(UBound(aKey),1) = aKey, but it also seems to just be pasting 137,000 versions of the first entry of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim a1(), a2(), i As Long, ub As Long

    ReDim a1(1 To 1, 1 To 137000)
    'load source array ("wrong" shape)
    For i = 1 To 137000
        a1(1, i) = i
    Next i

    ub = UBound(a1, 2)

    ReDim a2(1 To ub, 1 To 1) 'resize a2 ("right" shape) to match a1

    ' "flip" the a1 array into a2 
    For i = 1 To ub
        a2(i, 1) = a1(1, i)
    Next i

    'drop a2 to worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Resize(ub, 1).Value = a2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. As an aside, my array is 1D and this process is not just copying it but turning it into a 2D array. Does an array need to be 2D to paste? Are there options for pasting 1D arrays?

Comment: Options for pasting 1-D arrays typicaly use `Application.Transpose()` but as you discovered, that has a limit on the size of array you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating an array for a single column and placing it in a column:

```
Sub qwerty()
Dim aKey(1 To 137000, 1 To 1) As Variant

For i = 1 To 137000
    aKey(i, 1) = Rnd
Next i

Range("A1:A137000") = aKey
End Sub
```