# Replacement (Hyperlinks.Add Anchor)

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

Is there such a command/method in VBA that operated the same way as
Hyperlinks.Add Anchor , but worked with variables , not with ranges ?

```
   book1.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(34 + (x - 1), (26 + (iLoop * 21)) + (y - 1)), Address:=data(x, y), TextToDisplay:=vata(x, y)
```

That instead of

```
 Cells(34 + (x - 1), (26 + (iLoop * 21)) + (y - 1))
```

there was a variable .

Comment: It seems to me that you are mixing up things here. Yes, this method requires a `Shape` or a `Range` as `Anchor`. Otherwise, Excel doesn't know where to attach it to. And of yourse you are free to "save" `Cells(34 + (x - 1), (26 + (iLoop * 21)) + (y - 1))` in a range variable in order to make use of it afterwards when executing [Hyperlinks.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hyperlinks-add-method-excel). But this doesn't change the fact that a Excel needs to know where to attach the hyperlink to (Anchor). So, either you pass it directly or indirect with a variable.

Comment: @Ralph , My mistake .did not need to attach the code .

Comment: I want to attach it to a variable (not range) , so i understand that Hyperlinks.Add Anchor did not work that way . I need to know :Is there such a command/method in VBA that operated the same way as Hyperlinks.Add Anchor , but worked with variables , not with ranges ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @EganWolf ,
I have 2 dynamic arrays, I want to create a 3rd din array (by connecting the first two arrays in the style of the method (Hyperlinks.Add Anchor)) and then insert the 3rd array entirely and right into Excel (in general, my main goal is to speed up the work my original program)

Comment: The question you have worded is misleading as you do not wish to load a single Hyperlink into a variable but rather a collection of hyperlinks into a variable and then bulk-assign this array to be your hyperlinks for the active sheet. So, basically your question should be how to "bulk-assign" an array or collection (of type Hyperlinks) to ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks (analog to pasting an array to a Worksheet.Range as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25020071/1153513). Is this correct? If so, then please reword the post a bit and the title of your post aswell.

Comment: @Ralph ,
I figured out how to solve the problem . Thanks for your help !

Comment: If you have figured out the solution then please post it here for others to see. Otherwise, this post is not helpful for StackOverflow (which strives to be a library or collection of working solutions for other users.